# React Native Expo Start ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConstants' of null, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, debugging, error-handling, expo, runtime-error

I meat The Error From React Native Expo Start
[On MacBook PC Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwZDe.png)

[On My Phone Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBeS6.jpg)

I have try to upgrade SDK Upgrade from 46 to 48.
and I just Built app ( eas build –p android --profile preview )
and try to Test ( npx expo start )

How can we take action to resolve this error please ?